# Reinstalling Windows 10, now getting "An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system"

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, ssd

Today I decided to add another SSD to my system and reinstall Windows 10 on that drive. I created the Windows 10 installation media (disc) and then inserted it, restarted my computer and then went through the setup. I formatted the other two drives that I had in there as well. So it was a clean install. I had an issue with the format, but I solved that. Then I began the installation process, and it got to 93% of the 2nd stage of the installation process. It stayed like that for three hours, so I turned the computer off. Then when I rebooted to try again, I was greeted with the message "An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system. Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete to restart"

I disconnected the drives and then went to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete... my keyboard doesn't work. I have a Corsair K95 RGB, the lights on the keyboard are on, but nothing happens when I type.

I'm currently stuck with a paperweight. Please can someone give me some ideas.

Thank you.

Comment: What issue did you have when you performed the format?  Have you tried to install Windows again?  If it was stuck at 93% then the installation was complete, which explains the error, you are now getting.  In other words, format the HDD again, and try again

Comment: Disconnect every possible peripheral and reinstall. Reformat the disk when the install starts.

Comment: You disconnected the drives with the system powered up?

Answer (score -1):

Since Windows only got to 93 percent thats why the operating system wasn't found I would press and hold the power to shut down the computer reinsert the 
W10 disk and start the installation over ... if that doesn't work I recommend killdisk or Dban to wipe your drives bits to 0's and restarting the installation process... Your keyboard might not work due to lack of drivers... during the installation process it might have never installed the generic io drivers

hope this helps... test your keyboard in BIOS this should work :)